# How to remove a git subtree prefix?

Tags: git, git-subtree

Meanwhile removing a subtree folder :

```
git rm -r my-subtree-folder
```

All the fines are gone but the subtree prefix is still there.

Ho do I tell git I don't want this prefix anymore?